# Android Toast Maketext function get in wrong looper

Tags: java, android, toast

My app is working not correctly. Exactly when I click one button, I am logged out automatically. Here there is source code.

```
protected void previewStack() {
        this.currentSubeditor.dataFromUIFields();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generating preview..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePostButtonState();
        Hype4DController controller = Hype4DController.getInstance();
        controller.previewStack(getApplicationContext(), this, this.stack);
    }
```

So I debugged on Toast.maketext() then it shows,

```
    public Looper getMainLooper() {
        return mBase.getMainLooper();
    }
```

And warn that this loop is not in correct.
I think this is because of Toast maketext() function. Because other functions are working correctly.
So anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you run it in another thread, you must execute Toast in the main thread, you can try this:

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generating preview..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But for me "can't resolve symbol 'activity'". Please help me more if you can

Comment: you need a activity to use runOnUiThread, if you are in activity, you can delete activity word, else you need pass it

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText()` should only be called from Main/UI thread :

```
 protected void previewStack() {
 this.currentSubeditor.dataFromUIFields();


 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generatingpreview..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
         });

  updatePostButtonState();
  Hype4DController controller = Hype4DController.getInstance();
  controller.previewStack(getApplicationContext(), this, this.stack);


        }
```